# Javascript error Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript

For my code:

```
var lambipirn = {

    initialize: function(kasutusKorrad, tööKorras, põleb) {
        this.kasutusKorrad = kasutusKorrad;
        this.tööKorras = tööKorras;
        this.põleb = põleb;
    }
    turnOn: function(lambipirn) {
        kasutusKorrad = kasutuskorrad - 1;
        return kasutusKorrad;
    }
};
```

I get error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier(…) line 8

What is the problem, what I am missing?

Comment: You have to have a comma between each key:value pair in an object literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comma between `initialize` value and `turnOn` key is missing. Like this (the difference is in line 6):

```
var lambipirn = {                            // ln 1
    initialize: function(kasutusKorrad, tööKorras, põleb) {  // ln 2
        this.kasutusKorrad = kasutusKorrad;  // ln 3
        this.tööKorras = tööKorras;          // ln 4
        this.põleb = põleb;                  // ln 5
    },                                       // ln 6
    turnOn: function(lambipirn) {            // ln 7
        kasutusKorrad = kasutuskorrad - 1;   // ln 8
        return kasutusKorrad;                // ln 9
    }                                        // ln 10
};                                           // ln 11
```

Also keep in mind, as @user3803723 said, that JavaScript is casesensitive and you should be careful when using `kasutuskorrad` or `kasutusKorrad`.

Answer (score -1):

Javascript is case-sensitive.

`kasutuskorrad != kasutusKorrad`